# I'm testing heartbleed but to my web server

Tags: python, macos, openssl, heartbleed-bug

I'm planning to show how heartbleed bug work in my class by making small exercising web server. so using virtual machine, i installed Ubuntu 14.04 OS, which has vulnerable version of openssl(1.0.1f). and installed apache2, made small web site. But when i run heartbleed python code to that web site in my mac os, i only got

```
`Connecting...
Sending Client Hello...
Waiting for Server Hello...
 ... received message: type = 22, ver = 0302, length = 66
 ... received message: type = 22, ver = 0302, length = 991
 ... received message: type = 22, ver = 0302, length = 411
 ... received message: type = 22, ver = 0302, length = 4
Sending heartbeat request...
Unexpected EOF receiving record header - server closed connection
No heartbeat response received, server likely not vulnerable enter code 
here`
```

Should it be vulnerable to this attack? I don't know why this result come out

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Also see [Heartbleed tag](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/heartbleed) on Server Fault, [Heartbleed tag](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heartbleed) on Information Security Stack Exchange, [Heartbleed tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/heartbleed) on Super User, etc.